# Not able to add .jpg image in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, image

I am trying to show an image in the customise popup for every feature in ArcGIS Online. For this purpose I am tring to add .jpg format image to ArcGIS Online. I believe this is an [acceptable format](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/supported-items.htm) but it still not letting me upload the file and is giving me the error that "The file is not supported".

My ArcGIS Online is a public account if it makes a difference and the image I am trying to upload is less than 1MB in size.

Comment: How precisely are you trying to do this?  Can you [edit] your question to include the steps you perform prior to seeing the message that "The file is not supported", please?

Comment: Could you share a link to the webmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulic accounts do not support file upload.

From the doc page
https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/add-items.htm

" In addition, organizational accounts can add image files and use the URL to show images in web apps, pop-ups, and so on. You need to share the CSV and image files with everyone (public) to see the URL in the item details page. "

Comment: Thanks Russ. So I believe I can upload the images on Flickr and use them?

Comment: I tried adding link from flickr in the customize popup and it worked. Thanks!!